# Apple Mac Certificate difficulties

Tags: xcode, macos, certificate, xcodebuild

Whereas I can build on Xcode 4 with my dev application Certificate, I used an installer certificate and imported it in the keychain manager and evaluated it with success.

It happend that I'm rejected during the build : "Code signing identity '3rd Party develooper Installer:Myname' does not match any valid, non-expired, code-signing certificate in your keychain"

To avoid differences, this string come from a copy-paste of my certificate in the keychain manager into the Code-signing/release of the Target.

NB : the debug/Release settings do not affect this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I let the certificate but changed the bundle identifier (in "Target/info") to match the same as in the itunes connect.